# All site content being dumped into one group after upgrade to organic groups 7.x-2.3

Tags: views, organic-groups, nodes

I recently upgraded to OG version 7.x-2.3 as part of the security bug fix for OG. Unfortunately, as was indicated, it certainly wasn't backwards compatible with the version of OG I already had installed, and it messed up my groups big-time. After going back and re-calibrating things (a fresh install isn't an option), I've got it almost back to where it was previous to the upgrade except for one major problem: the Views integration is causing a huge issue, maybe because it doesn't seem to have been upgraded along with the rest of OG.

Since I was getting the error message "call to undefined function og_get_group()" after the upgrade, I searched and found a somewhat helpful post here: https://drupal.org/node/1522026#comment-7823093. The function has been deprecated in 7.x-2.x. I first tried implementing the patch in post #4, but I couldn't get that to work. I then went with post #3 and commented out the line "// $group = og_get_group($entity_type, $etid);" along with doing the other tweaks called for in post #3.

I no longer get the error message, but, unfortunately, every bit of content from everywhere on my website is now showing up within one of my groups (only articles published by group members are supposed to be posted there, but literally ALL of the content from my entire site is now in one of my groups), and none of the other previous articles are showing up in my other groups.

I then went ahead and changed the code back to the original code that was there before, while commenting out that same line, and I'm still getting the same result.

In other words, every bit of content is getting dumped into that one group. Here is the relevant bit of code that I customized to get me to this point, which is located in the og_views.module file:

```
function og_views_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance,
$langcode, $items, $display) {
$element = array();

if ($field['field_name'] == OG_VIEWS_FIELD && !empty($entity->{OG_VIEWS_FIELD}    
[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) {
$view = $entity->{OG_VIEWS_FIELD}[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == '__global' ?     
variable_get('og_views_global_view', 'og_nodes') : $entity->{OG_VIEWS_FIELD}    
[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];

if ($view = explode(' ', $view)) {
  list($etid) = entity_extract_ids($entity_type, $entity);
  //$group = og_get_group($entity_type, $etid);
  $element[0] = array('#markup' => views_embed_view($view[0], !empty($view[1]) ?     
$view[1] : 'default', !empty($group) ? $group->gid : ''));
   }
}

return $element;
}
```

Or maybe it's not the og_views.module file that needs to be modified at all, but some other file? Can anyone help me with this?